# How to read data block from a file using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

When using raw pointers I was able to do that:

```
std::vector< Vector3* > vertices;
Vector3* v = new Vector3[amount];
fread(v, sizeof(Vector3), amount, file);
for ( int i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    vertices.push_back( &v[i] );
```

now, how to do the same with smart pointers? I was tried something like this:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Vector3 > > vertices;
std::unique_ptr< Vector3 >* v = new std::unique_ptr< Vector3 >[amount];
fread(v, sizeof(Vector3), amount, file);
for ( int i = 0; i < amount; ++i )
    vertices.push_back( std::move( v[i] ) );
delete [] v;
```

does it have any sense? It compiles, and it works, but I'm afraid the last instruction (`delete [] v;`) is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Take it easy

```
std::vector<Vector3> vertices(amount);
assert(!vertices.empty());
fread(&vertices[0], sizeof(Vector3), amount, file);
```

Comment: I was blind. Thank you for showing me that I don't even need any pointers ;)